# Computing a conservatively rounded square of a double on broken compilers

Tags: interval-arithmetic

I am trying to compute $x^2$ where $x$ is a double precision floating point number.  I need conservative rounding, which means I need $x \cdot x$ rounded up and $x \cdot x$ rounded down.  If the rounding mode is set to FE_UPWARDS, the code is

```
double lo = -(x * -x);
double hi = x * x;
```

However, this does not work for me on clang 3.4: the compiler notices the "common subexpression" and does only one multiply.  Does anyone know how to convince clang to not do this, ideally without harming other optimizations?  In particular, I would like to avoid noninline functions.

Comment: "I need conservative rounding, which means I need $x \cdot x$ rounded up and $x \cdot x$ rounded down." I'm a little confused; what's the difference between those two expressions?

Comment: If the floating point number $x$ is considered as a real number, $x \cdot x$ is a real number that usually cannot be represented as a float.  I need float point numbers on either side.

Comment: I believe GCC has a flag that forces the compiler to do IEEE conforming floating point arithmetic. This would presumably eliminate the "optimization" of the double negation.

Comment: Yes, gcc falls into the class of "nonbroken compilers" for purposes of this question.  Clang lacks -frounding-math.

Comment: llvm (and thus presumably clang) has an enable-unsafe-fp-math option - what does clang -mno-enable-unsafe-fp-path do?

Comment: enable-unsafe-fp-math makes clang even more broken than it already is in terms of floating point behavior.  Not enabling unsafe math means it is only as broken as discussed in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this can be fixed by packing the interval bounds into SSE registers and performing all the interval operations with SSE as described in

http://hal.inria.fr/docs/00/28/84/56/PDF/intervals-sse2-long-paper.pdf

This should be faster than my current code anyways, and clang shouldn't apply SSE within the same instruction.

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler has `nextafter`, then you can do something like this, which works regardless of which rounding mode is set:

```
double x2 = x*x;
double lo = nextafter(x2,-1);
double hi = nextafter(x2,x2+1);
```

but I don't know whether `nextafter` is inlined (probably not).

Comment: Is there a reason for the $x2+1$ argument to `nextafter`, instead of just $+1$?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving, `nextafter(x,y)` returns the next representable floating-point value after `x` in the direction of `y`.

Comment: If you want to go a specific direction, your best bet is to just pass + or - infinity to nextafter.  If x2 is so big that `x2+1` == `x2`, you'll just get `x2` back from [`nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter).

Answer (score 2):

This is a sad answer, so I am not going to accept it in hopes that someone else has a better solution:

```
double hi = x * x;
double lo = (2*epsilon-1)*hi;
```

This is safe because if we're rounding up,
$$\begin{aligned}
-\left((2\epsilon-1) \odot (x \odot x)\right) &\le (1 + \epsilon)^2(1-2\epsilon) x^2 \\
&\le (1+2\epsilon+\epsilon^2)(1-2\epsilon)x^2 \\
&\le (1-\epsilon^2-\epsilon^3)x^2 \\
&\le x^2
\end{aligned}$$
so our code correctly computes the lower bound.